# Android Studio Gradle not Building Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I was using my android Studio very well. I don't know what happened and now I am getting only Building "xxxx" Gradle project info whenever I want to create my new project. I am unable to open any new project. Please help. I don't have even 10 reputations to upload the screenshot.

I think my Gradle is not working. How can I reset or restart my Gradle ?

Comment: your Building success or not?

Comment: First i created the project with name "Project" and it was showing same as "FinalProject". After that i stopped android studio with my task manager. Again launched android Studio and "Project " was there in recent projects list. I opened that project and nothing was there as in screenshot. From there i tried to create new project "FinalProject" and again nothing happened just Showing "Building 'FinalProject' Gradle project info".

Comment: you can try ReBuild your project??

Comment: I tried that also...Showing same all files are up-to-date. Nothing happening. No activity no xml file.

Comment: you try this file->Invalidate caches and restarts ..this only my opinion

Comment: It didn't work but i fixed the problem by downloading gradle-2.2.1-all.zip from https://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and pasting it inside .gradle->wrapper->dists. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have updated your gradle build tool.
Go to file>setting>build,execution deployment> gradle> check your gradle tool version

Comment: Good thinking ... saved my lots of time and effort.. thanks (y)

Comment: Bhoops It can be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I had many hours trying to figure this out.

I have followed just about every Stack-overflow article on the issue.

The cause for me was my **Anti-virus and Firewall settings. I turned these off,** and restarted my Android Studio opened my application I was trying to build it all downloaded what it needed and sync'd nicely. Problem solved, relief as I have been literally days on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

File -> Settings -> Compiler -> Gradle -> VM Options:
`-Xmx256m`

Comment: Your method didn't work for me. I fixed the problem by downloading gradle-2.2.1-all.zip from https://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and pasting it inside .gradle->wrapper->dists. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was failing a class because of this issue. I solved it by

1) Do not delete the Android Studio Version You Downloaded, Leave it intact 
2) Google search an older version of Android Studio, in my case, 2.1.1
3) Download it and install, CHOOSE CUSTOM INSTALL
4) A message should appear saying approximately "Another version of Android Studio has been discovered, the installer will only download the missing files"
5) Confirm by starting a new project

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem. Had to wait for 30 minutes for the project to built. But then it was working properly again. So maybe waiting is a solution.

Comment: I've left it to build for two hours. So this may not be the case